# JAXB troubles when trying to unmarshall a BES-XADES signature document

Tags: java, jaxb, xades4j

i need your help : please, please please.
I've a Xades-signed XML document that i receive as a byteArray : so i convert my byteArray to a String.
After, i try to unmarhall so that i obtain a Java Object mapped.

The result is that i get an instance of "MyJavaObj" with all informations but Xades-Signature. My signature is null in the Java Object while all other informations are well-mapped. The following is my java method. Please, help me to get the object signature in the instance of MyJavaObj.

```
<school>
    <documentVersion>2.10</documentVersion>
    <teacher>
    .....
    </teacher>
    <student>
        <name></name>
        <age></age>
        ....
    </student>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-2b72d2f4-4794-4a8b-8cbf-4c74d33629a7">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
        ........
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        .......
    </ds:Signature>
</school>
```

this is the method to convert

```
public static MyJavaObj unmarshallBinary(final byte[] pByteStr) {
    try {
        final String xmlFlow = new String(pByteStr, "UTF-8");

        final StringBuffer xmlStr = new StringBuffer(xmlFlow);
        // Unmarshalling with JAXB
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated.package");
        // marshaller
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        // Unmarshalling 
        final JAXBElement<MyJavaObj> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(
            new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStr.toString())), MyJavaObj.class);
        return root.getValue();
    } catch (final Throwable excep) {
        excep.printStacktrace();
    }
}
```

MyJavaObj result = unmarshallBinary(..a ByteArray..);

result.getDocumentVersion() : returns 2.10;

result.getStudent() : returns the students;

result.getSignature() : return NULL;

The file MyJavaObj.java is well annotated

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "My_Java_Obj", namespace = "urn:my_java_obj", 
propOrder = {"documentVersion", "teacher", "student","signature"})
public class MyJavaObj {

    @XmlElement(name = "documentVersion", required = true)
    protected String documentVersion;
    @XmlElement(name = "teacher", required = true)
    protected Teacher teacher;
    @XmlElement(name = "student", required = true)
    protected Student student;

    @XmlElement(name = "Signature")
    protected Signature signature;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String id;
    .....
    getters and setters
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `Signature` element is in the `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` namespace so you need to include this in the `@XmlElement` for the `signature` field.

```
@XmlElement(name="Signature", namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")
protected Signature signature;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Hello @Blaise, Signature is java.security.Signature?

Answer (score 0):

my solution is bit different

i used uddi-ws. Maven dependency is here:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.juddi/uddi-ws -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.juddi</groupId>
        <artifactId>uddi-ws</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

In class:

```
//in my case, import org.w3.x2000.x09.xmldsig.SignatureType isn't working
import org.w3._2000._09.xmldsig_.SignatureType;

//Signature declaration    
private SignatureType Signature;

//namespace is important part, without namespace, it returns null
@XmlElement(name = "Signature", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")
public SignatureType getSignature() {
    return Signature;
}
```

More info:
https://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2006-December/000674.html